# How do I find out what my SQL Server database audit records contain?

Tags: security, database, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I need to find out if my SQL Server 2005 database audit records contain the required information that I need. Where or how can I find this out?

Comment: Are you asking how to read what is stored in the database?

Comment: I need to make sure that each audit event record sufficient information in the audit trails such as date/time of the event, user ID, source, target, type of event, and sucess/failure.

Comment: Who maintains/controls the database? I am sure they can help you out and get the information you need quickly.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to use SQL Management Studio to view your database tables, columns, and type of data stored within it. You can also view the triggers, procedures, and functions. Whoever controls this database would have access to this software as it comes with every sql server install. If a lot of these terms make no sense to you, then you might want to contact the database administrator for help getting and verifying the information you need..

You would need a full read access account though to the server to see all elements of the database.  The database administrator is the best person to contact as they would know the layout, schema, and relationships.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Management_Studio